# Five Nights At Freddy's Age Rating Confusion

Tags: five-nights-series

So I've been aware of the Five Nights At Freddy's game for a few years and as far as I know it is an adult horror game and definately not suitable for children.

My son told me this morning that his 9 year old friend was playing it. I had a google and from what I can tell there are now several "Freddy's" games although it still seems to be an adult horror franchise.

I don't seems to be able to find an age rating for the game(s) - what is befuddling me even more is that searchin on Amazon brings up Five Nights At Freddy's action figures clearly aimed at children and also kids pyjamas!

I see several sites where people are giving a wide ranging assemsnent of how scary the game is but it must have an age rating surely.

Is there like a 'kids' version of the game or something or a spin off game which is why there are pyjamas and toys on Amazon?

Sounds like I don't want my child playing it or watching it anyway but I'm confused about the blurred lines of the content and would appreciate someone who knows the franchise putting me straight about the age rating and if there are child friendly versions or a cartoon or somting that explains pyjamas!

Comment: Most kids will play games no matter the age rating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Five Nights at Freddy's is a game series that has gained some pretty huge traction with younger children. Largely this is from YouTube channels that target their videos at children of about this age, just about every YouTube channel has done a video of themselves playing a d reacting to a fnaf game.

Is it an 'adult' game? It deals with some mature themes such as child abuse, murder and predators. But it's generally all implied, there is no detailed graphic content and any gore/violence is depicted in low quality cartoon like segments (borrowing an art style from old Atari 2600 games if that helps).

There is only one version of the game series, all of these games are horror titles and follow the same story line. However the popularity with younger audiences due to its massive impact through YouTube has spawned toys, pyjamas etc as you've noted.

The mature themes in these games are generally pretty subtle, and the unsubtle parts of the game are just simple jumpscares (where the enemies in the game jump out making a loud noise to startle the player) and a general feeling on tension from playing the game.

Bottom line, there is very little in these games that can just be given an age rating. There is no realistic gore, nor sexual content or anything like that. Whether you think your child would be safe enjoying this series is largely down to you knowing your child. The series is similar in 'scariness' to the early Childs Play films - corny and goofy, but if you find that kind of thing scary, you're better off leaving it be.

Answer (score 4):

The ESRB doesn't seem to have reviewed FNAF to give it an age rating.

But here on this steam post, seems to be a breakdown of what the rating would be, and why. https://steamcommunity.com/app/319510/discussions/0/412447613570515249/#c412447613573825769

> if the esrb rated this it would probably be "T" because the eyes on the game over screen would count as gore; the esrb doesn't take scariness into consideration as it is subjective: if a game has blood then that is a fact, but if it is scary then that is an opinion; since some people find the game scary but others don't, they would not take scariness into consideration; fnaf 3 would definitely get a T because and the esrb has a rule that any game with in it gets at least a T.

Common sense media also seems to go for a Teen rating https://www.commonsensemedia.org/app-reviews/five-nights-at-freddys

But as the comment by @Ave said, kids will often play/watch stuff not caring about the rating. And it can be fine most of the time.

You know your kid; will jumpscares and a little bit of gore prevent him from sleeping at night, or will it be just fine?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would have to say that the game is complete nonsense. All you do is survive from 12:00 am to 6:00 am and try not to die from the animatronics that are roaming around as you are working. The game does not have any gore or blood, but it does have mature scenes like murder and all that stuff. I would recommend kids to be ages 12+ to be able to play the game.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, FNaF's "Story" is not for kids (BTW the only way to actualy find the "Story" is to watch youtube or have a child who can spot anything and everything while being scared) but the game is fine, depending on if your child get's scared or not is the real question. I would recommend finding and buying the free game Freddy Fazbear's Pizzeria Simulator as it is an official game (the only parts that are anything like the original games is on day 2 and night 2 inside the room where there are vents). If your child is under age 12 however I do not recommend these games or especially the VR version which is only purchasble and even scary with an actual VR headset.

Answer (score 0):

FNAF is geared towards younger kids. I have played with my children since they were 9. It is jump scares for the most part. Someone hides in a dark restaurant and they jump out and scare you to death...no big deal. I have seen far worse in "Happy Wheels" as far as blood and gore is concerned. (look that one up, it is truly gory.)
When we went Christmas shopping these last two years, some well named department stores had FNAF gear/ clothing for infants and moms. Honestly, they were cool.

Answer (score 0):

You should let your kid play FNAF, it is not bad. Best age is 8-9+ for the jump scares, but that's it.